# Database size different after export/import

Tags: mysql

I had to export mysql database using mysqldump for backup reasons.

To compare the size given by phpmyadmin, I downloaded the dump on my local machine then import the dump using SQLYog into a local database.

Now, when I compare the size given by phpmyadmin on my machine and the remote machine, I end up with the imported database on my local machine to be smaller than the one on the remote machine :

- remote machine database size : 112,3 Mib
- local machine database size : 95,7 Mib

I would like to know what could be the reasons for such a difference ?

Cheers

Answer (score 5, accepted):

112,3 Mio what? Rows? b?

If it's storage size, there's not much to worry about, it's about how disk space usage is optimized (vacuum/optimize table).
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/optimize-table.html

On the other hand if it'S rows, you'll have to track down the tables that differ and figure out why.

use(replace schema name)

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME, table_rows, data_length, index_length, 
round(((data_length + index_length) / 1024 / 1024),2) "Size in MB"
FROM information_schema.TABLES WHERE table_schema = "test"   
union all
SELECT 'total', sum(table_rows), sum(data_length), sum(index_length), 
sum(round(((data_length + index_length) / 1024 / 1024),2)) "Size in MB"
FROM information_schema.TABLES WHERE table_schema = "test"   group by 1
```

Comment: It is the total table size, so I guess it is storage size is it ?

Comment: yep, check the link above, storage size may vary for the same data depending on how optimized it is. Use my query to find if there are any missing rows

Comment: No probs. Common 'scare'. Easiest way to demonstrate these inconsistencies is to just copy a database within the same server, and you will immediately see differences, even though they are identical (for example copy prod to a new one called Playground - i do that for some tests)

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: Sorry about the initial answer.

Did the DB have triggers/procedures ? If you did not export the file via a user with trigger/procedures privileges they will not be included in the export.

And also by default routines are skipped and the triggers are usually exported only by the root user.

Comment: Database size comparison, not dump size. Dump size will often be smaller because of indices

Comment: there's no triggers / procedures / routines on the db