# Why is mysql database larger after importing it?

Tags: mysql, sql

I exported a mysql database from phpmyadmin on a shared hosting. It's size was approximately 500 mb however after importing it on a centos 7 apache server, it's size was 700 mb.

I am wondering why this is?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Database size different after export/import](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21087865/database-size-different-after-export-import)

Comment: what exactly was 500mb, the export file? are they innodb tables? what version of mysql from where it's exported ato where it's imported?

Comment: note also that there may be differenct compression settings: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-compression.html

Comment: Yes, the export file is 500 mb and they are innodb tables. I imported it to phpmyadmin on another server and it became 700 mb.